# Why does Octave output $ g = [... ...] $

Tags: machine-learning, octave, linear-algebra

When I run this code (in a programming assignment for Coursera):

```
J = 1/m * [-y.*log(sigmoid((theta)'*X))-(1-y).*log(1-sigmoid((theta)'*X))]
```

where `m = length(y)`, `y` is an m-dimensional vector, `X` is an m*2 matrix, and `theta = 0.1`, Octave outputs:

```
g =

   [long (#rows)*2 matrix, each entry <1 but extremely close to 1]

g =

   [another long (#rows)*2 matrix as before]

J = 

   [(#rows)*2 matrix with entries such as 3.4932e-002 and 7.8914e-005]
```

What is `g`? I never defined it, and it does not appear in my code, yet is outputted with some seemingly unrelated numbers? (I know that the function itself may have problems, but that is a separate issue from what I'm interested in here. I figured that if I know what `g` is, I might be able to troubleshoot better. If you have any comments on the function, please don't hesitate to point out what's wrong.)

Comment: You have two calls to the function `sigmoid`, which is not a built-in function. So there must be some Octave code for that, which produces the output you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a statement (inside a function or otherwise) which is not terminated with a semicolon, the output of that statement will display on the terminal.

Assuming that this is the only code you're running, then my guess is that inside your `sigmoid` function there is a statement of this kind:

```
g = dosomething()   % note: not semicolon terminated!
```

resulting in terminal output during its execution.

The fact that `g` is reported twice in the terminal also makes sense, since you are calling the `sigmoid` function twice in that expression you just wrote.

Also, for the sake of clarity, please do not refer to your one-liner as a *function*, since that means something entirely different in the context of programming.